# Extra long loading time on Angular/django app

Tags: angularjs, django, pagespeed

I just lauched a website http://www.dicorico.com running on AngularJS and Django for the back-end. The performances of Google Page Speed insight are not great and my Google anaytics indicates a page loading time under Chrome of 10 sec on average since launch on 22nd of October ... I'd like to identify the issue and have no clue where to start looking. Your help would be much appreciated.

Note, the app uses http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/171/enable-rich-social-sharing-in-your-angularjs-app to render HTML so that the content is crawlable by google.

Thanks, 
Laurent

Answer (score 1):

You need to first exclude the fact that it's your code that made the performance suffers. To debug the performance of django projects, use [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) in your dev environment.

There are too many other facts that could also slow down your website, the instance you use might not be performant enough to handle the traffic, or you are doing some backend process in crontab that eats up the resource, or your database is not optimized, or you simply didn't configure web server correctly, etc.

You might need to login into the box and check the memory/cpu/disk usage to determine where the bottleneck is, then try to improve that. There's no straight answer for that, hope it helps.